# Non native Qt file dialog add system explorer bookmarks

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, window

In the application that I work on, I need to use a QFileDialog that is non-native ([`QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum)) because we need to add some custom logic in the folder selection (like if the folder contains a file, this part is out of the scope of this question). I can add the desired paths on the side bar by using:

```
QFileDialog *fd = new QFileDialog(parent, caption, updateLastAccessedDir(dir));
fd->setOptions(options | QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
QFileInfoList drives = QDir::drives();
for (auto d : drives)
  fd->sidebarUrls()->append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(d.path()));
fd->sidebarUrls()->append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation)));
fd->sidebarUrls()->append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation)));
fd->sidebarUrls()->append(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation)));
```

I want to be able to also add the bookmarked locations that the user has in the native file explorer. However, I do not know how to get the list of these paths.

**Is there any way of getting the list of bookmarked paths in the native file explorer in c++?  This is a Ubuntu and Windows application so it would be perfect if the solution is not OS-dependent (which I'm afraid will not be possible).**

Comment: Isn't that list stored in the Windows Registry? If yes, you might try to modify the entries, so that the native file dialog could show it.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself properly. I need the non-native dialog for other reasons that are not related to the missing bookmarks. I need to add the bookmarks to the non-native dialog rather than my custom URLs list to the native one.

Comment: I see. If you need to modify the non-native dialog you could find the widget that holds the bookmarks. For example: `dialog->findChild<QListWidget *>();`.

Comment: Adding and/or modifying the sidebar URLs is easy, I show it in the provided example. My problem is that I cannot get the list of bookmarked paths to add them to the sidebar URLs list.

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu(should also be same to other distribution), the native bookmark configuration is located in file '$HOME/.config/QtProject.conf', like:

```
shortcuts=file:, file:///tmp, file:///home/hs, file:///home/hs/Downloads
```

but i don't know about windows.

Comment: Is that a standard settings file that can be accessed through a `QSettings` object?  If so, perhaps that's a clue to a portable implementation?